# 32 bit exec fails to start but works when started through ltrace/strace

Tags: linux, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32 bits binary (running on a 64 bits host) that fails to start when started alone, returning an error when loading a shared library (cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory).
But it runs perfectly when I start it using ltrace or strace (I tried to find the point of failure)...

What's wrong? I checked the library exist, I tried to add it to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I also checked /lib/ld-linux.so.2 exists...

The host is running RedHat-EL 5.6...

Comment: Is `ldd` able to find all needed libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You need 32-bit version of libraries to run 32-bit applications on 64-bit system. Unfortunately Redhat doesn't have package like ia32-libs which would install most of them, it is supposed that you should install all 32-bit applications with yum and it will install the appropriate libraries for you. If your application is third-party, try installing 32-bit version of each library it needs, they usually have .i586 suffix, so you execute something like "yum install libusb.i586".

Comment: I have the 32 bits libraries. Without them it should not run when started using ltrace/strace.
It looks like a cache problem, but I can't find the library that failed in the ld cache, so it's in another cache...

Comment: Does ldd correctly show all libraries ?

Comment: Yes. The executable is on a NFS share, and the problem seems to have disapeared... It really looks like a cache issue, but as it now works, it becomes hard to trace it further... Anyway, thanks for the help.